# Android: how to customize a textview or a listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, textview

I am trying to create something similar to it.

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a textview or listview. I tried to use a TextView and see what came up but I faced the following issues:

- My title is outside the textview (which is a different textview), the reason I create a difference textview for my title was that I want the title with a different font.
- Also I have no idea how to create that line between bullet points.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Interns"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="defaultPosition"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/internsTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textAbout"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Title"

        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textInterns"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="List of items"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_website"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/visti_site"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_language_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="3dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/email_us_text"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email_green_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="3dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />


     </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: If you're talking about the pin (bullet with line) on the left of the text, this can be achieved through 9 patch image and setting it as background or right drawable. I think its possible to achieve it using StateList drawables as well.

Comment: Yes, i want to create exactly what is in the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that each card in your image holds a TextView for the title and then a ListView or RecyclerView for the bullet points below the title.

The individual bullet points can be made with a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/line"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/circle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/circle"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/circle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `circle` and `line` drawables are simple shapes:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="#caf"/>

</shape>
```

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="#caf"/>

</shape>
```

[image]

The last piece of the puzzle is making it so that the line is invisible when for the last bullet point. A simple way to do that would be to set its visibility based on whether or not you were binding to the last item in the list. If you were using a RecyclerView, it might look like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...
    if (position == getItemCount() - 1) {
        holder.line.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.line.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Native and simple.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I think that my example have many textview inside one textview? Not sure. I saw that app and took it as an example. So, does this solution assume that all bullet points are inside one textview(if possible). I am trying to get the same feel and look as the image, for example, all bullet points with the white background and the layout with grey background.

Comment: =/ I am having issues in creating more than two. any suggestion?For example, I need 4 of these. @BenP.